# Getting a No Class Definition Found Error in mistake?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, debugging, junit

I am writing an android app but using JUnit to test it out some of the more java-specific functionality before creating activities and the android-specific functions. As I write out the JUnit tests and execute them bit by bit, I am finding failures at the line `dbHelper = new DatabaseSystemHelper(context, null, null, 0);`

```
public DatabaseSystem(Context context) {
   dbHelper = new DatabaseSystemHelper(context, null, null, 0);
   database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}


class DatabaseSystemHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
...
    DatabaseSystemHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        setDatabaseValues(context);
    }


**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper**
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at edu.project2.systems.DatabaseSystem.<init>(DatabaseSystem.java:58)
    at edu.project2.systems.DatabaseSystem$SingletonHolder.<clinit>(DatabaseSystem.java:193)
    at edu.project2.systems.DatabaseSystem.getInstance(DatabaseSystem.java:203)
    at edu.project2.systems.DatabaseSystemTest.setUp(DatabaseSystemTest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 42 more
```

I am at a bit of a loss. It seems that my code never gets past the line for making a new DatabaseHelper object. In fact, when I "step-into" the call, the debug cursor never even gets into the constructor. Any advice would be great

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Using Eclipse Kepler on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure the class  SQLiteOpenHelper is available to the JVM at runtime.

The NoClassDefFoundError usually occurs when a class needed to compile the project is present during build time but missing during run time.

Ensure the class is included both in the build path and the classpath.

Comment: My build path included Anroid 4.4.2, Android Dependencies, and Android Private Libraries, JUnit 4. I have also added in the JRE Library. So it seems my buildpath should have it. The class path is generated automatically by Eclipse so I assumed those are fine?

Comment: yes if you are using eclipse it automatically includes all classes in the classpath too

Comment: To be honest I am not an android developer. Is the "SQLiteOpenHelper" class dynamically loaded during runtime. If so one will have to explicitly include it in the classpath

Comment: I wonder if that means it only works inside an Android device/emulator? Is it possible to get it working within a JUnit test?

Comment: I am looking into the android.test packages and wondering which test-class I should extend to properly test SQLIteOpenHelper? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

I got the tests to work by creating a separate Android Test Project and making my classes extend the AnroidTestCase class. https://developer.android.com/tools/testing/index.html

I know this answer isn't fully fleshed out, but in short it seems that you cannot use POJO's or run the regular JUnit/JVM when you are dealing with android specific classes since those classes need the Android emulator/devise to run on.

Here is what my test class looks like (keeping in my that it running in the android VM)

import android.content.Context;
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;

```
public class DatabaseSystemsTest extends AndroidTestCase {
    private DatabaseSystem dbSystem;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        Context context = getContext();
        DatabaseSystem.setContext(context);
        dbSystem = DatabaseSystem.getInstance();
        dbSystem.getDbHelper().onCreate(dbSystem.getDatabase());

    } // end of setUp() method definition
}
```